# Showing certain sum as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, elementary-number-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $e(\beta) = e^{2 \pi i \beta}$.
I am reading an article, where the author defines the following sum
$$
S(N) = \sum_{0 \leq x \leq N, x \equiv g (mod \ q)} \Lambda(x) e(f(x) \alpha), 
$$
where $f$ is a polynomial in one variable over $\mathbb{Z}$, $\alpha$ is a real number and 
$\Lambda$ is a von-Mangdoldt function.

Then the author says that
$$
S(N) = \int_0^N e(f(z) \alpha) \ d \Psi(z),
$$ 
where 
$$
\Psi(v) = \sum_{t \leq v, t \equiv g (mod \ q)} \Lambda(t).
$$
I know the definition of Riemann-Stieltjes integral, but I am having trouble showing this. I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you google "Riemann–Stieltjes Integrals with α a Step Function" then you see a pdf file that you need. Step function condition on g in Riemann-Stieltjes integral, allows transitions from series to integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for generic Riemann-Stieltjes integration, when you have something like
$$ \int_0^N f(t) dg(t),$$
you are summing together partial sums of the form
$$ \sum f(\xi_i) [g(x_{i+1}) - g(x_{i})]$$
behind the scenes, as it were. In other words, we are multiplying values of $f$ by changes in $g$ locally.

Let us consider a simplified integral,
$$ \int_0^N f(t) d \lfloor t \rfloor.$$
The say to think about when $g = \lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ changes here. At each integer, $\lfloor t \rfloor$ changes by $1$. So at $1$, the integral contributes $f(1) \cdot (\lfloor 1 \rfloor - \lfloor 1 - \epsilon \rfloor) = f(1)$. Similarly, newt $2$ the integral contributes $f(2)$. So
$$ \int_0^N f(t) d\lfloor t \rfloor = \sum_{n = 1}^N f(n).$$

In this question, your $g$ changes value at integers $t \equiv g \pmod q$, at which point it grows by $\Lambda(t)$. This is why the integral is equal to that sum.

Comment: I was reading an analytic number theory textbook and it said $\sum_{1 \leq n \leq N} f(n) = \int_1^N f(t) d \lfloor t \rfloor$. Is this a typo in the book then? Because by the argument you given me above it looks like $\sum_{2 \leq n \leq N} f(n) = \int_1^N f(t) d \lfloor t \rfloor$? Thank you very much!